# Help me identify this story about a posthuman child on the run in an Amish reserve

Tags: story-identification, transhuman

I think I read this book around 8 to 16 years ago, but I think it was a few years old at that point.

What I remember of the plot:

- The singularity has taken place, most of the world are transhuman
- There are large reserves where baseline humans (such as the Amish) can live  as though the singularity hadn't occurred
- The plot concerns a posthuman child (girl?) who ends up "on the run" (perhaps after an argument with their parents, or it could have been just for the adventure) in one of these reserves
- They end up befriending one of the baseline humans (I think it was also a child, possibly male) during the adventure
- > at some point the regular human dies, I think due to some industrial-type accident
- The posthuman child attends a funeral and has to be told that cat ears --possibly emotion-reactive e.g.

--are not suitable formal mourning attire for a baseline human funeral

Comment: It reminds me of "Transcension" by Damian Broderick, but the "inappropriate cat ears" were for a wedding rather than a funeral.

Comment: Looking at the blurb for Transcension I don't think that's the one I'm looking for. But I'll add it to my to-read list, thank you.

Comment: Can the OP edit the post to include a valid youtube link?

Comment: Updated... I don't think this was as good as the original video, but best I could find that wasn't an extended review.

Comment: We been spending most our lives
Livin' in an Amish paradise